# Selecting quarters within a date range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, between

I have a table that has school quarters and their start and end dates.

```
|yrq |start_date|end_date  |
|--------------------------|
|B233|2013-01-07|2013-03-23|
|B232|2012-09-24|2012-12-20|
|B231|2012-06-25|2012-09-13|
|B124|2012-04-02|2012-06-21|
|B123|2012-01-09|2012-03-27|
...
```

Getting the yrqs exclusively, meaning the yrqs fall entirely within the date ranges:

`SELECT yrq FROM yrq WHERE start_date>='2012-02-01' AND end_date<='2013-02-01';`

All but the first and last yrqs are returned (`B124, B231, B232`), even though the dates fall within `B233` and `B123`. Good to go!

I found out how to get the yrqs inclusively, meaning if a date falls in the middle of a yrq, include it (flipped the '<' and '>' signs and start and end dates passed in):

`SELECT yrq FROM yrq WHERE start_date<='2013-02-01' AND end_date>='2012-02-01';`

This returns all of the quarters listed and no other quarters. Good to go!

The query I am having trouble with is getting a yrq where the start and end dates are completely within it. Example: I want to find the yrq for the date range `2013-02-01` to `2013-02-15`, which would be `B233`.

I am calling a php function that runs the query. I am passing in an inclusive flag, and the case I don't have the answer to should return a result in the inclusive case. To encapsulate all inclusive cases, I was planning on running the query I don't have the answer to first and if it returns an empty set, then run the inclusive query above. If there is a more elegant way, I am all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I already solved the inclusive case. Just had my tasks for this ticket written on the white board and didn't think to exclude the problems I already solved. The query I already wrote: `SELECT qtr FROM qtr WHERE start_date>='2011-09-12' AND end_date<='2013-02-02'`

Comment: You say "if *a* date falls in the middle..."  Which date?  Can you give us more input/output examples?

Comment: Edited my question to satisfy this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns yrq's wherein the parameters are inside start_date and end_date. Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT *
  FROM yrq
 WHERE '2013-02-01' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
   AND '2013-02-15' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/980e7/1)